# Two commuting isometries $A_1$ and $A_2$ such that $A_1A_1^*+A_2A_2^*=I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space and $\mathcal{L}(E)$ be the algebra of all operators on $E$.

Recall that an operator $T\in \mathcal{L}(E)$ is said to be isometry if $T^*T=I$.

> I want to find two **commuting** isometries $A_1$ and $A_2$ such that
>   $A_1A_1^*+A_2A_2^*=I$.

I ask this question because I want to show that the equality
$$\left\|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^dA_k^*A_k \right\|=\left\|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^dA_kA_k^* \right\|,$$
need not hold in general even if the operators $A_k$ are **commuting**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully I didn't do any mistake.

**This is not possible.**

Indeed, if $A_1A_1^*+A_2A_2^*=I$, multiplying on the LHS by $A_1^*$ you get
$$A_1^*A_1A_1^*+A_1^*A_2A_2^*=A_1^* \\
A_1^*+A_1^*A_2A_2^*=A_1^* \\
A_1^*A_2A_2^*=0 \\
$$
Multiply on the RHA by $A_2$ to get 
$$A_1^*A_2=0 \\
A_1^*A_2A_1 =0$$

Now, since $A_1,A_2$ commute you get 
$$A_1^*A_1A_2=0 \\
A_2=0$$

Comment: So, it is possible that the equality
$$\left\|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^dA_k^*A_k \right\|=\left\|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^dA_kA_k^* \right\|,$$ holds for commuting operators?

Comment: @Student No, the above only shows that it is not possible to get $$A_1A_1^*+A_2A_2^*=I$$ But maybe you can get a different operator of norm one...And I am not sure if the same idea would show that it is not possible for 3 operators to get $A_1A_1^*+A_2A_2^*+A_3A_3^*=I$.

Comment: Thank you. I hope to give me an example if you know.